# Exporting Excel Inside Service

Tags: excel, delphi, service, export-to-excel

Good Evening!

I have built an Service App in Delphi, which should generate an excel and send it by email a few times per day.

Basically, I have my query components well configured (SQLQuery, Provider, Client and DataSource), and all the process work properly when I'm debugging the service in the IDE.

The problem is when I try to install my service and run it without Delphi, the program runs until this line:

`Excel.Application.Workbooks[1].SaveAs(pFileName + '.xls');`

**EDIT:** In the case above, the pFileName variable was provided with 'C:\', which means I'm giving the full path.

I've got the Exception, and here is the message:

**SaveAs method of Workbook class failed**

This makes me think the problem is not in the code, but something in my computer (some kind of configuration).

I've configured the service with my user, so I have all permissions, also I could generate txt files within the service, but not the xls (excel) file.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer while I was typing this question. Even though I'm using Windows 7, this worked for me:

> When using Windows 2008 **server x64**, create the following directory to
> enable Excel importing and exporting:
>
> **\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop**
>
> When using Windows 2008 server x86, create the following directory to enable
> Excel importing and exporting:
>
> **\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop**

Source: [Export To Excel error - Oracle Blog](http://oraclebrasil.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/export-to-excel-error-saveas-method-of-workbook-class-failed-or-open-method-of-workbook-class-failed-in-fdm/)

*Note: I even deleted the folder and tried again to be sure this was the solution. Thanks!*

Comment: That's the wrong solution. You're writing it to a privileged folder (Windows). You should create a folder in the proper location (under the Users\Public tree), and specify the path and filename when you save the exported file. Users can then also reach the file if needed in that location; non-admin users can't get to the Windows folder if UAC is enabled.

Comment: You may find [GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992) useful.

Comment: @ken I was providing my 'C:\' path to save files, the same place I create some .txt log files. The service (configured with my user) could create .txt files in the 'C:\' directory, but not the .xls file. I'm not saving my .xls files inside the windows directories, it looks like the excel.exe uses this windows folder to store temp files. Isn't it strange? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying a full path and so will be attempting to save the file to whatever happens to be the working directory of your service. It appears that the working directory for your service is a directory that does not exist.

The appropriate solution here is to provide a full path to the file. Since your goal here is to save a file temporarily so that you can then attach it to an e-mail, it makes sense to save to the temporary directory. Find the temporary directory by calling `GetTempPath`.

Comment: Please, could you look for the answer I gave to Ken below? I answered after your answer, there I mentioned that I was giving my 'C:\' path, and I could create .txt files in this directory, which means I have the rights to. Thanks a lot, you're always helpful!